# best practice for cxf ws client to send request to server (soap)

Tags: performance, web-services, cxf, webservice-client, webservices-client

I have a spring webapp. There is a screen need to make a call to another webservices (Soap protocol- not restful). I am using cxf to develop that web service client with contract first approach. basically, I follow the cxf sample code:

```
customerServiceService = new CustomerServiceService(wsdlURL);
CustomerService customerService = customerServiceService.getCustomerServicePort();
customerService.getCustomersByName("AAAA");
```

So far so good. But the number of calling that web service from my app now is about 10k/day. Do you know how to improve my code or add some parameters to cxf configuration to optimize the performance for that high volume?
I am not able to modify server code. The question is for my client code only.

Comment: 10k/day is not hardly high volume, not even one request per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must not be creating webservice client per request. If yes than create a bean of the client and inject it in spring configuration.

Cxf can be configured through SpringBus so configure cxf bus and provide no. of connection as per your requirement.

```
SpringBus bus = new SpringBus();
        bus.setProperty(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, Boolean.TRUE);
        bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_KEEPALIVE",Boolean.TRUE);
        bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_TIMEOUT",Boolean.FALSE);
        bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.MAX_CONNECTIONS","totalConnections"));
                bus.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.MAX_PER_HOST_CONNECTIONS","connectionsPerHost"));
```

Default Total Connection is 5000 so default may be enough.
I think this configuration should give you a performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

One of the improvements I can think of is, avoid creating Webservice object per request. As long as you have not modified the interceptors etc, clients are thread safe. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079866/how-to-use-cxf-client-in-thread-safe-way/29185152#29185152) for more info.